# Extract data from from git hub usi git api in python

Tags: python, github, github-api

I want to extract a user's public profile details along with the name of the repositories they are contributing to and finally the number of commits made by that developer on those repositories using a python scrip and I want to log it.

Answer (score 0):

to extract user data:

```
user_url = f"https://api.github.com/users/{user}"
user_response = requests.get(user_url)
user_response_dict = user_events_response.json()
```

repositories:

```
user_repo_url = f"https://api.github.com/users/{user}/repos"
user_repo_response = requests.get(user_repo_url)
response_dict = user_repo_response.json()
```